# How can I set the state of an object in this class hierarchy?

Tags: oop, generics, interface

I have designed my classes with this hierarchy to achieve

1. `RepositoryBase` to have some functionalities that can be used by derived classes.
2. The derived classes implement *validation* and *saving*.
3. Use the `IRepository` interface (rather than numerous customer interfaces) to register with a IoC container to get the instance of the repository, for example `CustomerRepository` in this example.

The problem that I have with this design is that the `customer` object is not known at the construction of the `CustomerRepository`. It has to be set before `save`.

How can I redesign this hierarchy to achieve the three that mentioned at the beginning of this question?

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public void string GetFullName();
}

public interface IRepository
{
    void Save();
}

public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository
{
    public abstract bool IsValid();
}

public class CustomerRepository : RepositoryBase<Customer>
{
    public void Save()
    {
        IsValid(); // Check for validation
        customer.GetFullName(); // Generate the FullName before saving
        // Save the data using some RepositorBase method.
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://designpattern.ninja/catalog/design-patterns/agnostic-repository). I documented a possible repository design just like the one you're looking for. BTW, I don't understand the part of: **The problem that I have with this design is that the customer object is not known at the construction of the CustomerRepository. It has to be set before save.**

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the text in bold?

Comment: The method ```public void Add(T someObject)``` in your code and ```Save``` in my code is indented to do the same. But your method can accept the object to be saved while mine not. Since my method can't take the object through ```Save```, I have to set the ```Customer``` state of the ```CustomerRepository``` before saving. If we use a ```IoC container```, once the container is setup with the ```CustomerRepository```, how can I inject the ```Customer``` object?